# I have basically the same API functions that connect my frontend to the flask backend. But why does one work and not the other?

Tags: javascript, flask, web-development-server

Here are my two API functions:

```
static LoginUser(username, password) {
    
    
    return fetch(`http://localhost:5000/userlookup`, {
      'method':'POST',
      mode: 'cors',
      headers: {
    'Content-Type':'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(username, password)

    })
    .then(resp => window.location.href="profile")
    .catch(error => console.log('error time!', username, password))
  }


static ShowUser(username) {
    
    return fetch(`http://localhost:5000/getprofile/`, {
      'method':'POST',
      mode: 'cors',
      headers: {
    'Content-Type':'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(username)

    })
    .then(response => response.json().then(data => {console.log(data)}))
    .catch(error => console.log('never went'))
  }
```

And this is part of app.py that uses Flask

```
@app.route("/userlookup", methods=['GET','POST'])
def userlookup():
    username = request.json['username']
    password = request.json['password']
    hashed_password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(password)
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
    print('got here')
    if user and bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, password):
        print('youre in')
        login_user(user)
        return username
    else:
        print('tripped')


@app.route("/getprofile/", methods=['GET','POST'])
def getprofile(username):
    username = request.json['username']
    profile = User.query.filter_by(username=User.username).first()
    print(username, profile)
    print('got here')
    return register_schema.jsonify(profile)
```

My `LoginUser` function works, but my `ShowUser` doesn't.  I can't spot the major difference that is causing this difference in outcomes.

I get this error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:5000/getprofile/. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
```

Which I read means that a header is missing, but I'm using the exact same header in `LoginUser`...so why doesn't it work?

My `ShowUser` function used to be a `GET` method and set up to have a parameter in the url, before I changed it...Is the fact that I changed it causing the issue?

Edit:
Also, my `ShowUser` function used to kind of work, back when it was something like

```
static ShowUser(username) {

   return fetch (`http://localhost:5000/getprofile/<username>`, {
   'method': 'GET'
```

My backend error is this

```
TypeError: getprofile() missing 1 required positional argument: 'username'
```

So I think my backend isn't seeing anything and my problem is in the `ShowUser` function...I think

Comment: It's the CORS setup in Flask - which I'm not familiar with. The error is saying that the server is not sending back a CORS header to allow the browser to make the API call. Perhaps this will help? https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: @seesharper, thanks, but I'm using the option under the "Simple Usage" title in your link that I think should take care of all routes

Comment: The 2nd parameter `JSON.stringify` doesn't make much sense. I don't think your login is really working

Comment: @GarrGodfrey hmm...it logs me in?

Comment: 1st problem: chrome does not support CORS on localhost.  There is a workaround where you must define a different host to point to 127.0.0.1

Comment: 2nd problem: you appear to just be sending the username in the body, not  a JSON object with a username property.  Unless the "username" you pass to these function is actually an object with multiple properties?

Comment: 1st problem.  I'm using firefox.  2nd problem.  you're right I'm not sending an object with multiple properties.  But is this the same problem you see in the `LoginUser` function?

Comment: Are `username` and `password` both strings? If so, there is no way the password is being sent to your login function.

Comment: yeah I just ran a `console.log(typeof(username))` and it is a string

Comment: I just tried to login with a bad password and it goes to the next page as if I'm logged in!  Looks like you're right.  I guess I have to look into making it a JSON object before I send it to the backend.